# How can I get test Ethereum on test network?

Tags: ethereum

I tried Rinkby test authenticated faucet but it is offline also tried to get test Ethereum from Ropstan network now I wanna is there anyway to get test Ethereum

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use the Kovan testnet instead. It has much faster block times.

You can get some Kovan test ether here: https://gitter.im/kovan-testnet/faucet